# How to create EF migrations with ConnectionStrings on Azure's ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

We recently moved from a local server for `dev` and a private server on the cloud for `prod` to Azure, where we have different slots (`dev`/`staging`/`prod`) and to SQL Azure as well.

Everything is running fine until I needed to create a new migration. We are using a Code First EF6 so, in order to create a migration I type on the console package administrator window the `add-migration Whatever099BriefDescription` command.

I instantly got a `NullReferenceException` referring to the connection string. We've got a `ConnectionStringFactory` class where we used to have an `#if DEBUG#` returning the correct connection string grabbed from the `Web.Config`.

```
public static class ConnectionStringFactory
{
    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        //USED JUST FOR CREATING MIGRATIONS
        //#if DEBUG
        //            return @"Data Source = SQLSERVER\LANSERVER; Initial Catalog = Project; user id = Project; password = asdf; MultipleActiveResultSets = true";
        //#endif

        var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Project"].ConnectionString;
        return connectionString;
    }
}
```

Since we're actually using the Azure's configuration connection strings (on Azure Portal panel) our `web.config` has no connection strings defined. So of course that `NullReferenceException` makes complete sense, because it's trying to get that string from a place where it can't get grabbed.

I could finally create the migration using again the `#if DEBUG#` annotation, providing the hardcoded connectionstring and of course deleting it afterwards.

This seems like an "odd" behaviour or at least not the optimal. Could you please share any advice on how could I create EF migrations without the needance of hardcoding temporarily the connectionstring so it could be "somehow" achieved to get it from Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, I think you can download the connection string from Azure, set the connection string as an environment variable then run the command `add-migration`. Regarding how to get the connection string from Azure,  please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/connection-string?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_config_connection_string_list).